# Git Hub action `on: release: type: [released]` ran when release deleted

Tags: github, github-actions

I have been experiementing with Github actions to automate our release pipeline. I have a workflow that I require to trigger only when a release is promoted from prerelease to release, so I have created my worklfow as follows:

```
name: Deploy To Prodcution
on:
  release:
    type: [released]
```

However, during my trials I deleted a release, and this workflow triggered and deployed the release I was trying to delete. Have I missed something when declaring when I want the event fired. Triggering a "released" event when deleting an event seems like it would be a pretty serious bug.

Addendum: The workflow also triggered when only updating the name of the release. No change from prerelease to release. It seems the `released` event type doesn't mean what it should considering there is a separate `prereleased` event type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation, it should be `types` not `type`

```
name: Deploy To Prodcution
on:
  release:
    types: [released]
```

However, This may trigger `created`, `released` and `published` in my experience which is not aligned on the description of action on [webhook events and payloads](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#release) redirected from [events that trigger worfklows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#release).

I have no correct answer for this issue, but trying to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `published` instead of `released`.
See documentation for on.release: https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhook-events-and-payloads#release

Comment: I've opted to use draft releases instead of prerelease for our deployments to staging, and then deploy to production on published, but this feels like a work around, not a solution. Even from the documentation there, I would not expect a deletion to trigger a "released" event

Comment: @AndyRyan for the staging/pre-release, I resorted to: protect the main branch, trigger a build/deploy to stage when a PR makes it to the main branch. As for releasing to production, I'm trying to do like you're doing: trigger on a well-crafted/documented release through the github console/ui, but it's not firing...